# How to get video metrics for each video for each day

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to get video metrics for each video under my channel using Java SDK.

```
videoMetrics = analytics.reports()
                                .query("channel==" + channelId, video_start_date, video_end_date,                                 "views,comments,likes,dislikes,estimatedMinutesWatched")
                                .setDimensions("day")
                                .setSort("-estimatedMinutesWatched")
                                .setFilters("video==" + videoId)
                                .setFilters("country==US")
                                .execute();
```

This request not providing the metrics for each video on a particular day. Can anyone suggest the issue and solution in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [reports.query](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/).

> The [YouTube Analytics
>   API's](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/)
>   reports.query method lets you retrieve many different Analytics
>   reports. Each request uses query parameters to specify a channel ID or
>   content owner, a **start date**, an **end date**, and at least one metric. You
>   can also provide additional query parameters, such as dimensions,
>   filters, or sorting instructions.
>
> **Metrics** are individual measurements of user activity, such as video
>   views or ratings (likes and dislikes). Dimensions are common criteria
>   that are used to aggregate data, such as the date on which the user
>   activity occurred or the country where the users were located. Filters
>   are dimension values that specify the data that will be retrieved. For
>   example, you could retrieve data for a specific country, a specific
>   video, or a group of videos.